# JavaFX ListView selectedItemProperty not firing on clearSelection(index)

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx, multipleselection

I am using JavaFX for the GUI of an application I am writing. I have a ListView and a Button in my GUI.

**I want the ListView to maintain multiple selection on mouse clicks and only remove selections when clicked again (this works).**

**I also need to validate that something has been selected in the ListView and disable the button if nothing is enabled (works on selections but NOT on deselections).**

Here is my code for the button enabling and disabling (this is not working):

```
//Binding used to enable and disable the button
    BooleanBinding validEntriesBinding = new BooleanBinding(){
        {
            super.bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
        }
        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            log.info("No individual item selected? " + 
                    (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty()));
            log.info("Selected items: " + listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().toString());
            return (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty());
        }
    };

    button.disableProperty().bind(validEntriesBinding);
```

Here is my code for capturing the mouse selections (this is working, solution developed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900478/mimicking-ctrlclick-multiple-selection-in-listview-using-javafx) *SO* answer by fabian):

```
//Example sourced from stackoverflow.com/questions/40900478/mimicking-ctrlclick-multiple-selection-in-listview-using-javafx
        //Answer by fabian
        //Must use MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED and not MOUSE_CLICKED, otherwise the selection does not work
        listView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
            Node node = event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();

            while(node != null && node != listView && !(node instanceof ListCell)){
                node = node.getParent();
            }

            if(node instanceof ListCell){
                event.consume();
                listView.requestFocus();

                ListCell cell = (ListCell) node;
                if(!cell.isEmpty()){
                    if(cell.isSelected()){
                        log.info("Clear selection...");
                          listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(cell.getIndex());
                              log.info("Selection cleared");
                    }
                    else{
                          log.info("Selecting...");
                        listView.getSelectionModel().select(cell.getIndex());
                        log.info("Selected");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    log.warn("Cell is empty... cannot select");
                }
            }
            else{
                log.warn("Unable to handle event for " + node.getId() + " " + node.getClass());
            }
        });
```

Here is what the output looks like when I run my app:

```
    //Before click, button disabled
    No individual item selected? true
    Selected items: []

    //First click selecting a cell, button enabled
    Selecting...
    No individual item selected? false
    Selected items: [SV124]
    Selected

    //Second click deselecting the first selected cell, button stays
    //enabled as the BooleanBinding never fires
    Clear selection...
    Selection cleared
```

Why does the `BooleanBinding` not fire on `listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(cell.getIndex());`? Or, more directly, why does the `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()` not fire when selections are empty? According to the Javadoc it should return null when empty, so shouldn't that be captured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that removing a selected *index* from the list view's selection model fails to invalidate the `selectedItemProperty()`. (That would appear to be a bug.)

It works if you bind to the `selectedIndexProperty` instead of the `selectedItemProperty`:

```
BooleanBinding validEntriesBinding = new BooleanBinding(){
    {
        super.bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty());
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        log.info("No individual item selected? " + 
                (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty()));
        log.info("Selected items: " + listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().toString());
        return (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty());
    }
};
```

and perhaps, since you have multiple selection enabled, it's better to bind to the *list* of selected items anyway:

```
BooleanBinding validEntriesBinding = new BooleanBinding(){
    {
        super.bind(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        log.info("No individual item selected? " + 
                (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty()));
        log.info("Selected items: " + listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().toString());
        return (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty());
    }
};
```

Note that if you make `validEntriesBinding` a local variable, it is prone to [accidental garbage collection](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html). You should make this a field instead:

```
private BooleanBinding validEntriesBinding ;

// ...

validEntriesBinding = new BooleanBinding(){
    {
        super.bind(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        log.info("No individual item selected? " + 
                (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty()));
        log.info("Selected items: " + listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().toString());
        return (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty());
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I think the switch to `selectedIndexProperty` should do the trick for me for now. I also took your suggestion and made `validEntriesBinding' a field. Should I open this as a bug with JavaFX developers / ask them about the expected outcome from this scenario?